# How can I get a text width?

Tags: gtk, vala

I want to modify a Gtk.Entry to fit its text width, how can I get the text width?. I've tried setting an average width for each character, but It don't work properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GTK+ widgets have their rendering layout done by Pango, so first, create a Pango `Layout` for your widget by calling [`create_pango_layout`](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Widget.create_pango_layout.html) with the text you want on your `Gtk.Entry` and then use [`get_size`](https://valadoc.org/pango/Pango.Layout.get_size.html) to get the dimensions.

Comment: Also, it is possible to get the existent Layout by calling [`Gtk.Entry.get_layout`](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Entry.get_layout.html):

    int width, height;
    entry.get_layout ().get_size (out width, out height);
    width = (width / Pango.SCALE);
    entry.width_request = width;